# I am trying to run a random variable multiple times

Tags: python

I am very new to python, and am running into an issue I don't fully understand. I am trying to get a random variable to run multiple times, but for some reason it just returns the same random value x times.

I am not entirely certain what to try aside from the code I have already done.

```
lowTreasureList = "50 gold", "Healing Potion", "10x Magic Arrows", "+1 Magic Weapon"

def ranLowLoot(lowLootGiven):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
    lootIndex = random.randint(0, len(lowLootGiven) - 1)
    return lowLootGiven[lootIndex]

lowLoot = ranLowLoot(lowTreasureList)

treasureSelection = int(input())

if treasureSelection == 1:
    numLowTreasure = int(input('How many treasures? '))
    for i in range(numLowTreasure):
        ranLowLoot(lowTreasureList)
        print(lowLoot)
```

When I do this I get the same random treasure (numLowTreasure) times, but I am trying to get it to select a new random treasure each time.

Comment: Small point: your `lowTreasureList` is a *tuple* rather than a list.

Comment: You assign a value to `lowLoot` exactly once. I think there's some fundamental conceptual misunderstanding behind this since you can't "run" a variable.

Comment: You're calling `ranLowLoot()` many times, but you're not printing those results. You're printing `lowLoot`, which is the result of only the _first_ call to `ranLowLoot()`.  I assume you meant to assign `lowLoot = ranLowLoot()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, it will help to read the documentation on [the `random` module](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#functions-for-integers).

There are three alternatives to random.randint that are more suited to your purpose:

- `random.randrange(start, stop, [step])`: step is optional and defaults to one. This will save you the `len(...) - 1` you are using to get lootIndex, since stop is an exclusive bound.
- `random.randrange(stop)`: uses a default start of zero and default step of 1, which will save you passing `0` as your start index.
- `random.choice(seq)`: you can pass your function's parameter `lowLootGiven` to this as `seq`, which will save you from using indices and writing your own function entirely.

As for why you're getting the repeated treasure, that's because you aren't updating your variable `lowLoot` in your for loop. You should write:

```
for i in range(numLowTreasure):
    lowLoot = ranLowLoot(lowTreasureList)
    print(lowLoot)
```

Last thing I want to say is that python is nice for writing simple things quickly. Even if there was some bigger context that you were writing this code in, I might have written it like this:

```
lowTreasureList = ("50 gold", "Healing Potion", "10x Magic Arrows", "+1 Magic Weapon")

if int(input()) == 1:
    for i in range(int(input('How many treasures? '))):
        print(random.choice(lowTreasureList))
```

Using the round parentheses around the tuple declaration like I did isn't necessary in this case, but I like to use it because if you want to make the tuple declaration span multiple lines, it won't work without them.

Reading documentation on standard libraries is something I almost always find helpful. I think Python's documentation is great, and if it's bit too much to digest early on, I found [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_overview.htm) to be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the main loop you are *discarding* the result of the call to `ranLowLoot()`. As a minimal fix, in the main loop assign the result of that function call. Use:

```
lowLoot = ranLowLoot(lowTreasureList)
```

rather than simply:

```
ranLowLoot(lowTreasureList)
```

As a better fix, ditch your function completely and just use `random.choice()` (which does what you are trying to do, with much less fuss):

```
import random

lowTreasureList = ["50 gold", "Healing Potion", "10x Magic Arrows", "+1 Magic Weapon"]

treasureSelection = int(input())

if treasureSelection == 1:
    numLowTreasure = int(input('How many treasures? '))
    for i in range(numLowTreasure):
        lowLoot = random.choice(lowTreasureList)
        print(lowLoot)
```